# "Convert to comment" option should be grayed out when not available

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I just tried to convert a post to a comment via the moderator menu, only to be presented with a plain-text page saying

> Comment must have a valid owner

Presumably this is because the owner was deleted.  Clearly the page already knows that a post doesn't have a valid owner, so can we get the "convert to comment" option grayed out in the mod menu in cases like this?